# Firebase firestore security rules allow if document ID contains string

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have got the following:

```
match /direct/{postId} {
   allow read, write: if postId.includes(request.auth.uid);
}
```

However, I would like to only allow read, write if the document ID (postId) contains the string. .includes is not working for me in security rules.

***Edit*: it should match a substring instead of the entire document id**

***Edit2***

[image: screenshot of a db]

**collection called direct where each document ID is a string which contains 2 uids in it’s name.**

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: try with equals to .

Comment: Are you trying to find out if `request.auth.uid` is **exactly** equal to `postId`, or just a substring?  A substring match seems kind of strange here.

Comment: it should match a substring instead of the entire document id

Comment: Please edit the question to show the specific query you're trying to allow with these rules that isn't working the way you expect.  It would help to see the actual data as well.  Rules by themselves don't mean anything unless paired with queries and data.

Comment: Ok ive made the edits

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The document ID is a string, and as far as I can see the [String class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String) in security rules doesn't have an `include` method.

It does have a `matches` method though, so you can use that to test whether the document ID contains a substring with a regular expression.

Something like:

```
match /direct/{postId} {
   allow read, write: if postId.matches(request.auth.uid);
}
```

A working read where the `postId` matches the UID of the user:

[image]

Trying to read another document:

[image]

**Update**: to test for a substring:

```
  allow read: if postId.matches(".*"+request.auth.uid+".*");
```

Comment: It does not work. Also, I’m very new with regex, how would I use it to create a rule of if string contains?

Comment: "it does not work" is not very easy to help with. I copy/pasted this rule from the Firebase console after testing it in the simulator. I also added screenshots of my test now. If you can't get it to work, I recommend trying again, and if it persists: posting your minimal code, or a screenshot of the simulator.

Comment: I now see what went wrong, and added a second test.