# Firestore rules: Property is undefined on object. for 'list' @ L6

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire

I am having an issue where I am trying to query a subquery by a field, and I have tried the emulator as well as firebase support (still on going, but not solutions yet).

When running the following query:

```
const queryByNumber = query(
  collectionGroup(this.firestore, 'residents'), 
  where('cellNumber', '==', number)
);
return from(getDocs(queryByNumber));
```

This query has the error of:

> Property cellNumber is undefined on object. for 'list' @ L6

This is what the rules look like at the moment

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{path=**}/residents/{residentDoc} {
        allow write: if resource.data.cellNumber == request.auth.token.phone_number;
        allow read: if request.auth.token.phone_number == resource.data.cellNumber;
        //allow read; //temp permission till support fix
      }
      match /Units/{unitNumber} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null;
        function residentDoc(residentId) {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Units/$(unitNumber)/residents/$(residentId))
        }
        
        match /pets/{petId} {
          allow write: if residentDoc(request.resource.data.residentId).data.cellNumber == request.auth.token.phone_number;
          allow read: if request.auth != null;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And this is the firestore data structure at the moment:

[image: firestore data structure]

I have tried to change my query to have the `array-contains` in the where clause, but that doesn't change much.

**Note: the `allow read` without the if check allows the data to be retrieved, so the query does work, just the rules to secure it are not`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was another query trying to get all resident data after the initial one was fired, which caused it to fail the rule because the second one wasn't querying by `cellNumber` anymore. I have changed the rules to validate by `UID` since that will always be provided

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this condition in your rules:

```
request.auth.token.phone_number in resource.data.cellNumber
```

The `in` operation in Firestore security rules is only defined for maps and lists/arrays, but your `cellNumber` field is a simple string value, which does not define an `in` operation as you can see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String).

If you want to check whether the phone number in the token is the same as the value of the field, use `==` instead of `in`. If you want to test whether it is *in* the field, consider using the [`matches` method on the string](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches).

Also see:

- [Firebase firestore security rules allow if document ID contains string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63326592/firebase-firestore-security-rules-allow-if-document-id-contains-string)
- [Using contains() with firebase rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65467896/using-contains-with-firebase-rules)

Comment: Hi sorry I have edited the rules/question, it was originally ```==``` but I changed it to ```in``` to try and get it to work with the ```array-contains```

Comment: Hi Frank, just checking if you managed to look at it again with my previous comment?

Comment: When you posted the question I spotted a problem and answered for that. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Understandable, thanks for the trying to help